# Difference between DialogPreference before and after AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

We are currently migrating to Androidx namespace with our Android app project. However I noticed that not only the namespace seems to have changed. For DialogPreference also some interfaces which were using before are now missing

- new interfaces: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/DialogPreference
- old interfaces: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/preference/DialogPreference

For example the following methods seem to be missing: onBindDialogView, showDialog, onDialogClosed.

Since we use some of these methods to influence the default behavior of the dialog, it is unclear to me how I should realize this functionality now. For example we are validating the input before closing the dialog, we are saving the value in a database instead of the sharedpreferences and adding some dynamic elements to the dialog.

Has anyone else already encountered this problem and found a solution? Did I miss anything in the documentation? Is there another concept that we can / should use?

It would be possible to use Fragments instead of DialogPreference but for small amounts of content (e.g. a list of tree items, where the user can choose from) this seems to be a lot of overhead for me...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting from androidx source files, I've migrated custom classes based on old *DialogPreference* to new *androidx.preference.DialogPreference* with the following procedure:

## Step 1

The old custom dialog class (e.g. CustomDialogPreference) based on legacy DialogPreference should be split into two separate classes:

1. One class (e.g. CustomPreference) should extend *androidx.preference.DialogPreference* and will contain only the code related to preference handling (data management).
2. Another class (e.g. CustomDialog) should extend *androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat* and will contain only the code related to dialog handling (user interface), including *onDialogClosed*.  This class should expose a static method *newInstance* to return an instance of this class.

## Step 2

In the main fragment handling preferences based on *PreferenceFragmentCompat* the *onDisplayPreferenceDialog* method should be overridden to show the custom dialog, e.g.:

```
    private static final String DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG = "CustomPreference";

    @Override
    public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
        if (getParentFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (preference instanceof CustomPreference) {
            final DialogFragment f = CustomDialog.newInstance(preference.getKey());
            f.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            f.show(getParentFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        } else {
            super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
        }
    }
```

Comment: same what I did. Just hadn't found the time to write an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @little_planet Can u pl show the contents of both custom classes as well?

Comment: almost 100% true for modern AndroidX as well: https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-3-ae9793fd31ec

Comment: Can please either of owner or @Livio provide working examples? I believe there are many of us that find your answers helpful but don't manage to get it working.

Comment: @Androidz I successfully followed this answer and migrated to AndroidX ColorPicker preference, embedded into my "ToDo Agenda". It works now.
See this commit: https://github.com/andstatus/todoagenda/commit/27cce2c0a0fcddfe22ce71efd86b88d04020c7b2

Comment: getParentFragmentManager() have to be changed to getFragmentManager()?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `DialogPreference`, you can write your own custom `Preference` with an `AlertDialog`.
This may be a workaround for those who don't want to deal with the `DialogPreference` and `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.preference.Preference;

public class CustomDialogPreference extends Preference {
    private final Context context;
    public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onClick() { //what happens when clicked on the preference
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("TITLE")
                .setMessage("message")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                    String preferenceKey = getKey(); //You can update the SharedPreference with the key
                    //....
               })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialog, which) -> {
                    //....
                })
                .create().show();
    }
}
```

`onClick()` and `getKey()` methods belong to the `Preference` class. The `context` object comes with the constructor and so on..

The key can be defined, as other preferences, in xml file or programmatically in the PreferenceFragment.

```
<com.myApp.CustomDialogPreference
    android:key="my_preference_key"
    android:summary="..."
    android:title="..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

A little hack for everyone who (like me) do not completely understand how we should combine `androidx.preference.DialogPreference` and `androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`:

**Step 1:**

In your `DialogFragment`'s `onAttach()` method get the value of your desired `SharedPreference` (get the key either from `newInstance()` method or just hardcore it inside) and save it as a variable. On the other hand, save your new value in `SharedPreference` before closing your `DialogFragment`. By doing so, you have created your "custom Preference".

**Step 2:**

Create empty `androidx.preference.DialogPreference` and use it inside your `PreferenceScreen`. Then combine it with your `DialogFragment` as described in 2nd step by @Livio:

```
private static final String DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG = "CustomPreference";

@Override
public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
        return;
    }

    if (preference instanceof CustomPreference) {
        final DialogFragment f = CustomDialog.newInstance(preference.getKey());
        f.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        f.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    } else {
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
    }
}
```

By doing so, you will get the same result with only difference that you need to deal with `SharedPreference` yourself inside your `DialogFragment`.